# Postgres: Erro ao converter data no Postgres 10

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, timestamp

Quando executo uma conversão de data no postgres 9.6 que tenho na minha máquina, ele corrige a data caso esta esteja inválida, o mesmo não está ocorrendo no postgres 10 que está em outra máquina:

**Postgres 9.6**

DateStyle = ISO, DMY
server_encoding = UTF8
TimeZone = America/Sao_Paulo

```
SELECT to_timestamp('01/12/2018 24:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24/MI/SS')
  Resultado: 02/12/2018 00:00:00
SELECT to_timestamp('31/11/2018 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24/MI/SS')
  Resultado: 01/12/2018 00:00:00
```

**Postgres 10**

DateStyle = ISO, DMY
server_encoding = UTF8
TimeZone = America/Sao_Paulo

```
SELECT to_timestamp('01/12/2018 24:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24/MI/SS')
  ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "01/12/2018 24:00:00"
SELECT to_timestamp('31/11/2018 00:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24/MI/SS')
  ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "31/12/2018 00:00:00"
```

Alguma pista de qual poderia ser a diferença entre os bancos ?

**EDIT:** Aqui tem uma informação de como deveria funcionar:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_timestamp/#crayon-5c2381f372207739024582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que a partir da versão 10 passou a rejeitar datas inválidas.
Veja as Release Notes (Apêndice E):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-10.html

E.9.3.6. Functions

Make to_timestamp() and to_date() reject out-of-range input fields (Artur Zakirov)